# Average precision and average recall both are always 0 in TFOD and not showing the bounding boxes

Tags: tensorflow, config, object-detection

While training with `TensorFlow Object Detection` API, I am getting the accumulated evaluation result always 0. Following is the corresponding verbose that I got:

```
Accumulating evaluation results...
DONE (t=1.51s).
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=  1 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets= 10 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
```

Why this is happening? As TFOD documentation I provided the `train.record` and 'test.record' files to the model. But didn't provide any validation or evaluation data-set or something like that separately as I didn't find anything as a requirement like this. Is it the reason for this?

Additionally here is the training command:

```
!python /content/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path={pipeline_fname} \
    --model_dir={model_dir} \
    --alsologtostderr \
    --num_train_steps={num_train_steps} \
    --num_eval_steps={num_eval_steps}
```

Here, I set the following values to these variables:

- pipeline_fname: 'ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config'
- model_dir: '/training' # just a sample folder to hold the model
- num_train_steps: 50000
- num_eval_steps: 1

Additional information:

- Pre-trained model used: 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
- Batch_size: 8
- Tensorflow-GPU 1.x used in COLAB
- NumPy==1.17.5 was installed beforehand as the latest version was creating an error called `Out of range: End of sequence` and which was occuring probably for another error called`TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. Both of them were fixed by downgrading NumPy version.

**EDIT:** Apart from this I have found another problem. While testing the output doesn't show any bounding boxes on test images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright! I have found the suspicious reason behind this. The problem is probably with the pre-trained model. Initially I was using `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17` as a pretrained model and getting the error. Therefore when I changed the model the error was gone. Currently I am using `ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29` which is an updated version of it. Following is a portion of verbose which shows hopefully now everything is going okay:

```
Accumulating evaluation results...
DONE (t=1.05s).
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.329
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.835
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.111
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.200
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.298
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.392
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=  1 ] = 0.206
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets= 10 ] = 0.439
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.441
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.274
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.409
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.502
```

**Edit:** The problem of not showing the bounding boxes was also fixed automatically after changing the pre-trained model as mentioned.